# Get code source of dynamically loaded HTML content (Chrome/Gmail)

Tags: html, ajax, dom, gmail

I am trying to access the HTML code source of AJAX dynamically loaded content. How could I do it? 
For example on Gmail, I am trying to access the HTML code of a given email discussion's content (the different entries of a given email discussion) which is loaded only when I click on this email discussion's line in the main list. The code source I can access is only the one of the page initially loaded (the list of all email discussions). Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right-click on the page and select "Inspect Element". The element view is updated when JavaScript makes changes to the page, whereas the "View Source" view only shows content from when the page was loaded.

Comment: Note: that's Chrome-specific.

Comment: The question title says Chrome.

Comment: This doesn't always work - the CSS inspector shows you what was actually rendered by the browser.  Sometimes, you have an error (like a missing/misplaced tag) that the browser will ignore that will cause some errors.  This will be evident in the source but absent in the inspector.

Answer (score 1):

If you right click -> "View Source", it will show you the contents of a reloaded version of the page you are on.

Using "Inspect element" (hotkey CTRL+SHIFT+i) in Chrome shows the source of the dynamic content.

Comment: In recent versions of IE: hit F12.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to bind event on the dom element that loaded after initial page load using ajax. If so then you can use jQuery library and you can use live method of jquery.

Here is a link for live method, you can check that.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

What you need 
Download jquery latest library (http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery)
and then include it in script within head
or you can use cdn `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js`

then do like following
        `<script>`
         `$(document).ready(function(){`
           `$("#ajax_dom_element_id").live('click_or_any_event',function(){`
             `code snippet you wan dot`
            `});`
       `});`
       `</script>`

I think it will be helpfull.