# Calling a view through jquery and parsing html

Tags: php, jquery

I have a page in php home.php and it has views something like this

home.php

```
<?php

?>
<div id="showView">
    <a href="#" id="user">Show User</a>
    <a href="#" id="car">Show Car</a>
</div>

<div id="userView">
    <p>This is view where user profile is shown</p>
</div>
<div id="carView">
    <p>This is view where user car is shown</p>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#user").click(function(e)
    {
        //This where I am confused
        var car = $("#carView").html();
        $("#showView").append(car);
    });
});
</script>
```

Now I am confused that how to pick `userView` and append to `showView` I tried a bit of coding but it didn't help and it didn't show result. Moreover is there any way that when that `userView` is appended then its `html` is shown when I `view-source` a page?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: just a side note `view-source` did not affected by javascript... (it's intended that way) what javascripts manipulates are DOM (Document Object Model), you can look on it using **inspect element**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get code source of dynamically loaded HTML content (Chrome/Gmail)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333889/get-code-source-of-dynamically-loaded-html-content-chrome-gmail)

Comment: Do you guys realize that there is another problem I asked? `var car = $("#carView").html();
        $("#showView").append(car);` these two lines doesn't work!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1) you generate the html on the fly using jquery (Not recommended)

```
<div id="showView">
    <a href="#" class="view_trigger" id="user">Show User</a>
    <a href="#" class="view_trigger" id="car">Show Car</a>

    <div id="view_content"></div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('.view_trigger').click(function () {

     var viewHTML = '';

     if ($(this).attr('id') == 'user') {

        viewHTML = '<div id="userView"><p>This is view where user profile is shown</p></div>';
     } else if ($(this).attr('id') == 'car') {
        viewHTML = '<div id="userView"><p>This is view where user car is shown</p></div>';
     }

      $("#view_content").html(viewHTML);
   });
});
</script>
```

2) show/hide the container on trigger

```
<div id="showView">
    <a href="#"  class="view_trigger" id="user">Show User</a>
    <a href="#"  class="view_trigger" id="car">Show Car</a>
</div>

<div id="userView" class="view_content" style="display:none">
    <p>This is view where user profile is shown</p>
</div>
<div id="carView" class="view_content" style="display:none">
    <p>This is view where user car is shown</p>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.view_trigger').click(function () {

     var viewHTML = '';
     $('[class=view_content]').hide();
     if ($(this).attr('id') == 'user') {
         $('#userView').show();
     } else if ($(this).attr('id') == 'car') {
          $('#carView').show();
     }

   });
});
</script>
```

I don't recommend any of these solutions, you should use MVC for a better code.